# Java - Return the node visited after node x in a pre-order traversal of BT

Tags: java

I am being asked to "Return the node visited after node x in a pre-order traversal of a binary tree" in Java for school. I have created a code to list all the nodes in pre-order, but I'm not sure how to print off a single node.

My first class to create the nodes is:

```
public class TreeNode {
int value;        // The data in this node.
TreeNode left;   // Pointer to the left subtree.
TreeNode right;  // Pointer to the right subtree.
TreeNode parent; //Pointer to the parent of the node. 

TreeNode(int value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.right = null;
    this.left = null;
    this.parent = null;
 }

 public void displayNode() { //Displays the value of the node.
    System.out.println(value + " ");
 }
```

I then have the class to build the binary tree. It also prints the whole tree in pre-order:

```
public class BTree2 {

TreeNode root;                // the first node in the tree

public boolean isEmpty() // true if no links
{
    return root == null;
}

private TreeNode addRecursive(TreeNode current, int value) {
    if (current == null) {
        return new TreeNode(value);
    }

    if (value < current.value) {
        current.left = addRecursive(current.left, value);
    } else if (value > current.value) {
        current.right = addRecursive(current.right, value);
    } else {
        // value already exists
        return current;
    }

    return current;
}

public void add(int value) {
    root = addRecursive(root, value);
}


void printPreorder(TreeNode node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(node.value + " "); /* first print data of node */
    printPreorder(node.left);   /* then recur on left subtree */
    printPreorder(node.right);  /* now recur on right subtree */
}

void printPreorder() {
    printPreorder(root);
}
```

This is where I get stuck: how do I print off the node that comes after a particular node, and not just the whole tree? I thought it would be:

```
 public TreeNode findPreorder(int key) // find node with given key  
{                            // (assumes non-empty tree)  
    TreeNode current = root;                // start at root  

    while (current.value == key) // while there is a match  
    {
        current = current.left;

        if (key < current.value) // go left?  
        {
            current = current.right;

        } else {
            current = current.right; // or go right?  
        }
        if (current == null) // if no child,  
        {
            return null;                  // didn't find it  
        }
    }
    return current;                     // found it  

}
```

But that's not working. This is my test code in my main:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    BTree2 tree = new BTree2(); 


    tree.root = new TreeNode(1); 
    tree.root.left = new TreeNode(2); 
    tree.root.right = new TreeNode(3); 
    tree.root.left.left = new TreeNode(4); 
    tree.root.left.right = new TreeNode(5); 


    System.out.println("Preorder traversal of binary tree is "); 
    tree.printPreorder(); 

    System.out.println("the node after 1 is " + tree.findPreorder(1).value);

}
```

My output is:

Preorder traversal of binary tree is 
1 2 4 5 3

the node after 1 is 5

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically use the same function for visiting in pre order manner with some modifications:

```
void findNextInPreOrder(TreeNode node, int key) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (node.value == key) {
       if(node.left != null){
          System.out.print("Next is on left: " + node.left.value);
       } else if (node.right != null){
          System.out.print("Next is on right: " + node.right.value);
       } else {
          System.out.print("There is no next node.");
       }
    }   
    findNextInPreOrder(node.left);   /* then recur on left subtree */
    findNextInPreOrder(node.right);  /* now recur on right subtree */
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! How would I call this in the main? I can't figure out how to input values for TreeNode type objects in the main. If I put in the value of the node, I get an error that int cannot be converted to TreeNode, or if I put in the one node that I have (tree.root) I don't get an output. Ex. Input: :System.out.println("the node after 1 in preorder traversal is "); tree.findNextInPreOrder(tree.root, 2); Output: the node after 1 in preorder traversal is

Comment: Yes, just call it with the root node, and the value you want to search.

Comment: sorry, I'm not used to how this works. Thanks, I've accepted it!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!! I also added an 'else' statement since that seemed to help me a bit with the implementation:

```
void findNextInPreOrder(Node node, int key) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (node.value == key) {
        if (node.left != null) {
            System.out.print("Next is on left: " + node.left.value);
        } else if (node.right != null) {
            System.out.print("Next is on right: " + node.right.value);
        } else {
            System.out.print("There is no next node.");
        }
    } else {
        findNextInPreOrder(node.left, key);
        /* then recur on left subtree */
        findNextInPreOrder(node.right, key);
        /* now recur on right subtree */
    }
}
```